# Fast sums of power algorithm

Tags: haskell, time-limit-exceeded

This [code](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/4f7c264e3cd0a8df8029) reaches time limit on 1 test case, solving this [challenge](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/functional-programming-the-sums-of-powers). The approach that I'm using is from the book *Algorithms Functional Programming Approach*, which is a backtracking depth searching method. How do I improve speed of this code? Or is there better way to do it?

```
searchDfs :: (Eq node) =>
             (node -> [node]) -> -- generates successor nodes
             (node -> Bool) -> -- is goal
             node -> -- first node
             [node]
searchDfs succ goal x = search' ([x])
  where
    search' s
      | null s = []
      | goal (head s) = head s : search' (tail s)
      | otherwise = let x = head s
                    in search' (succ x ++ tail s)

type Degree = Int
type CurrentSum = Int
type CurrentNumber = Int
type Node = (CurrentSum,CurrentNumber,Degree,Goal)
type Goal = Int

succN :: Node -> [Node]
succN (sum,i,d, goal)  = [( sum+i'^d, i', d, goal) | i' <- [(i+1)..goal], sum+i'^d <= goal ]

goal :: Node -> Bool
goal (sum,_,_,m) = sum == m


countSols :: Degree -> Goal -> Int
countSols d m = foldr (+) 0 $ map (\(sum,i) -> length (searchDfs succN goal (sum,i,d,m))) startingNumbers
  where startingNumbers = [ (i^d,i) | i <- [1..m], i^d <= m]

main = do
  m <- readLn
  d <- readLn
  let c = countSols d m
  print c
```

Comment: [Completely changing the code is not fair.](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765). I've rolled back Rev 3 → 2.

Comment: Links can rot. [Please include a description of the challenge here in your question.](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/1993)

Answer (score 2):

- The `search'` could could be written more idiomatically (but not necessarily faster) as

  ```
  search' [] = []
  search' (x:xs) | goal x    = x : search' xs
                 | otherwise = search' (succ x ++ xs)
  ```
- The `Eq` constraint on `searchDfs` seems to be unused.
- In `succN`, you are calculating `sum+i'^d` twice (unless the compiler optimizes that away, but it’s better not to rely on that). Also, it will calculate it for all values of `i'` until `goal`, although you probably want to abort early. Maybe using `takeWhile` would be better:

  ```
   succN (sum,i,d, goal) =
       takeWhile (\(s,_,_,_) -> s <= goal)
                 [( sum+i'^d, i', d, goal) | i' <- [(i+1)..goal]]
  ```
- It looks as if the `d` and `goal` field of your `Nodes` is always the same. Then you shouldn’t have it as part of the `Node`, but rather pass it around explicitly. You can do that without modifying `searchDfs`!

Answer (score 0):

It was because of `i^d` generating too big number that `Int` can't hold, it became unresponsive/froze.
Also because computing same `i^d` on different nodes was making it slower. Now it computes them once. Then uses map lookup.

```
import Control.Monad (guard)
import qualified Data.Map.Strict as Map
import Data.Map ((!),fromList,Map(..),member)

-- depth first search higher order function
depthFirstSearch :: (node -> [node]) -> -- successor node generator
                   (node -> Bool) -> -- is goal checker
                   [node] -> -- starting root nodes
                   [node] -- goal nodes
depthFirstSearch succ goal roots = search' roots
  where search' [] = []
        search' (x:xs) | goal x = x : search' xs
                       | otherwise = search' (succ x ++ xs)

type Degree = Int
type CurrentSum = Int
type CurrentNumber = Int
type Node = (CurrentNumber,CurrentSum)
type Goal = Int

-- generates valid successor nodes
succN :: Goal -> Map Int Int -> Node -> [Node]
succN goal _map (i,sum) = do
  i' <- [(i+1)..goal]
  guard (member i' _map)
  let sum' = sum + _map!i'
  guard (sum' <= goal)
  return (i',sum')
-- checks if the node is the goal
goalN :: Goal -> Node -> Bool
goalN goal (_,sum) = goal == sum

-- counts solutions
solCount :: Degree -> Goal -> Int
solCount d goal =
  let roots = rts d goal -- [(i,i^d) | i <- [1..goal], i^d <= goal]
      _map = Map.fromList roots
      nodes = depthFirstSearch (succN goal _map) (goalN goal) roots
      c = length nodes
  in c

rts :: Degree -> Goal -> [Node]
rts d' g' = do
  let d = fromIntegral d'
      g = fromIntegral g'
  a <- [(1::Integer)..(fromIntegral g)]
  let aNth = a^d
  guard (aNth <= g)
  let bNth = (fromInteger :: Integer -> Int) aNth
      b = (fromInteger :: Integer -> Int) a
  return (b,bNth)

main = do
  g <- readLn
  d <- readLn
  print $ solCount d g
```